# Image are not aligning right in sections

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using freewall jquery plugin for images layout my first section is working fine,
http://csdm4.com/projects-industry/ although it's height isn't fine too. I'm using following code

```
 var wall = new freewall(".leadership-desktop");
    wall.reset({
        selector: '.image-block',
        animate: true,
        gutterX:10,
        gutterY:10,
        onResize: function () {
            wall.fitWidth();
        }
    });
    wall.fitWidth();
```

Layout isn't working fine on other sections.

Comment: First of all, your image are really heavy. Then, there must be an option in Freewall plugin that should fit to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing CSS styles are running two different themes which is not only a bad idea, but also is interfering with the style control of your freewall plugin.

The best idea is to ensure that the outer category section has a "position:relative" and you need the panels not to be negatively affected by the theme styles.  I recommend that you take on board what @enguerranws is saying about your image sizes being far too heavy too.  An image's natural size should not be much different to the dimensions which you are allowing as viewed on your website.

Finally, it will serve you well if you study an online CSS tutorial or two.. Once you understand how CSS really affects everything you see on the page - then you will enjoy web creation a lot more and find it a lot easier.  Start with something like this http://www.w3schools.com/css/ , and Google for more tutorials like this http://www.csstutorial.net/

Hope this helps... giving you a detailed rundown of all the things you need to correct and change would not really help you... :)

Comment: Glad to see that your site link is now positioning the images correctly :)